# Switch between displayed data

Tags: angularjs

I've started looking at AngularJS a few hours ago so I'm settling into how things work. As part of a basic example, I'm trying to figure out how I switch between displayed data in a table.

At the moment, I've got the following as my basic app;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-app="applicationMain" ng-controller="controllers.app.main">


            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <button>Toggle</button>
                    <td>{{item.name}}<td>
                </tr>
            </table>


        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        var controllers =   {
            app :   {
                main    :   function($scope){
                    var s   =   $scope;
                    s.items =   [
                        {
                            name    :   "Pizza",
                            price   :   100
                        },
                        {
                            name    :   "Burger",
                            price   :   45
                        },
                        {
                            name    :   "Kebab",
                            price   :   85
                        }
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        var app =   angular.module("applicationMain", []);
        app.controller('controllers.app.main', controllers.app.main);


    </script>
</html>
```

Fairly simple. Scoped array of objects with name and price fields, where the name of each is displayed in a table using `ng-repeat`

What I'd like to do is when I click the Toggle button, it switches between displaying the data of item.name to displaying data of item.price.

Is this something that can be done within the angular expression of the `<TD>` tags, or would a function be the way to go?

If I was using regular old JS for example, I might do something like this;

```
var activeField = item.name;
if (activeField == item.name){
    activeField = item.price
} else {
    activeField = item.name
}
```

However, I tried something similar by creating a 'switchField' function in my controller, but Angular reports that 'item is  not defined' (essentially a scoping issue) even when defining it at $scope.item.price and $scope.item.name respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, using ngClick, ngShow and ngHide:

```
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <button ng-click="toggleIt()">Toggle</button>
            <td ng-show="toggle">{{item.name}}<td>
            <td ng-hide="toggle">{{item.price}}<td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And add this to the controller:

```
        s.toggle = true;

        s.toggleIt = function() {
           s.toggle = !s.toggle;
        }
```

Comment: Works wonderfully! I'd hoped to keep it as a single TD and modify in-place but it's simple and elegant. I've just modified it a little and in the button ng-click, simply calling "toggle = !toggle" works (and the function in the controller isn't needed).

Comment: If you want to keep it as a single TD, you can try this: <td><div ng-show="toggle"> {{item.name}} </div> <div ng-hide="toggle"> {{item.price}} </div><td>